# Why all my dwellers complain about carrying too much stuff?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I finally had a big wave of dwellers reaching all their SPECIAL to 10. so I started sending them with the damage reduction pet into the wastelands where the best started at lvl 1 and made it like after close to 6 days with 3 med's left from alone home by stating a sentence alike "Thats all I can carry, so I go home now".

quite reasonable by the amount of items he found up to that time.

Today a similiar thing happened. but this time it happened to ALL my dwellers at a time. one even turned back after just have been out for 2 hours and only carrying 3 items while complaining about thats all he can carry.

While the other too had quite a lot of stuff allready (but anyway not equally much).

So is there any known bug?
Or is there a limit (for what ever purpose) o0f the sum of all collected items of dwellers currently expoloring the wastelands at a time?

Or what else might be the reason for a dweller returning from the wastelands since "he can't carry more then 6 items"?